# Having some trouble with jQuery mobile code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, append

I am developing a jquery mobile webpage. In one of the pages i would like to implement an RSS reader. I found an RSS reader online that looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/CustomTheme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <style type='text/css'>
        .ui-footer .ui-btn-right {
        }
        .articleContent > table > tbody > tr > td > font > br {
            display: none;
        }
        .articleContent > table > tbody > tr > td > font > br + div {
            display: none;
        }
        .articleContent * {
            font-size: medium !important;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>




<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

// ISCPA added search filter, home icon, updated CDN-Hosted links
// forked from sumukh1's "forked: RSS Reader with jQuery Mobile" http://jsdo.it/sumukh1/4Ton
/* configuration */
var maxLength = 20; /* writing HTML */
document.write('<div data-role="page" id="list">' + '  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">' + '    <h1><span id="widgetTitle">...</span> ' + '      <span style="font-size: x-small">(HTML)</span></h1>' + '  </div>' + '  <div data-role="content">' + '    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="articleList">');
for (var i = 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
    document.write('<li id="list' + i + '"><a href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '">&nbsp;</a></li>');
}
document.write('    </ul>' + '  </div>' + '</div>');
for (i = 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
    document.write('<div data-role="page" id="article' + i + '">' + '  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">' + '    <a href="#list" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-back="true">Home</a>' + '    <h1 id="articleHeader' + i + '">&nbsp;</h1>' + '    <a href="#" id="openButton' + i + '" data-role="button" data-icon="plus"' + '      class="ui-btn-right" rel="external">Open</a>' + '  </div>' + '  <div data-role="content">' + '    <div id="articleContent' + i + '" class="articleContent"></div>' + '    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">' + '      <a href="#article' + String(i - 1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l"' + '        data-inline="true" class="prevButton">Prev</a>' + '      <a href="#article' + String(i + 1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r"' + '        data-inline="true" class="nextButton" data-iconpos="right">Next</a>' + '    </div>' + '  </div>' + '</div>');
} /* JSONP */
$(function() {
    // getOnlineFeed('http://www4.lehigh.edu/news/rss/LUnews_rss.xml');
    getOnlineFeed('http://www4.lehigh.edu/news/rss/LUnews_rss.xml');

/*
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml');
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.fremont.k12.ca.us/site/RSS.aspx?DomainID=1&ModuleInstanceID=4613&PageID=1');
  getOnlineFeed('http://news.google.com/news?hl=ja&ned=us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&output=atom&topic=h');
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.appbank.net/feed');
  getOnlineFeed('http://japanese.engadget.com/rss.xml');
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.bebit.co.jp/index.xml');  
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.ntt.com/rss/release.rdf?link_id=ostop_service_rss');
  getOnlineFeed('http://feeds.feedburner.com/gapsis');
  getOnlineFeed('http://octoba.net/feed');
  getOfflineFeed('google_news_jsonp.js');
*/
}); /* functions */
var listEntries = function(json) {
    if (!json.responseData.feed.entries) return false;
    $('#widgetTitle').text(json.responseData.feed.title);
    var articleLength = json.responseData.feed.entries.length;
    articleLength = (articleLength > maxLength) ? maxLength : articleLength;
    for (var i = 1; i <= articleLength; i++) {
        var entry = json.responseData.feed.entries[i - 1];
        $('#link' + i).text(entry.title);
        $('#articleHeader' + i).text(entry.title);
        $('#openButton' + i).attr('href', entry.link);
        $('#articleContent' + i).append(entry.content);
    }
    $('#article1 .prevButton').remove();
    $('#article' + articleLength + ' .nextButton').remove();
    if (articleLength < maxLength) {
        for (i = articleLength + 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
            $('#list' + i).remove();
            $('#article' + i).remove();
        }
    }
};
var getOnlineFeed = function(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?callback=listEntries&hl=ja&output=json-in-script&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&v=1.0&num=' + maxLength);
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
};
var getOfflineFeed = function(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', url);
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
};
//]]>  

</script>


</body>


</html>
```

Ok this is a javascript that will dynamically create the page and everything. However i already have the page (in which i have a panel too) and what i am trying to do is integrate the code there. The page i have looks like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="news" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Espacio Joven</li>
            <li><a href="#news" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#agenda" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Agenda</a></li>
            <li><a href="#info" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#activities" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#alDia" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Al Dia</a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">La Noche Es Joven</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#mypanel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>News</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="RSSclass">    

        </ul>   

    </div> <!-- /content -->
</div>
```

Can someone help me configure the RSS code so that it creates the posts inside the

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="RSSclass">    

</ul>
```

that i have? I tried to tweak the code , eg i deleted the lines that create a page (i have a page so i dont need it) , instead of document.write i used append , so that to append the albums inside the listview , but still i have many many problems with it and it doesnt look good.

In case someone wonders , i tried to change the code to something like this :

```
$(document).on("pageshow", '#news', function() {

// ISCPA added search filter, home icon, updated CDN-Hosted links
// forked from sumukh1's "forked: RSS Reader with jQuery Mobile" http://jsdo.it/sumukh1/4Ton
/* configuration */
var maxLength = 20; /* writing HTML */

alert("Hello World!");

//Not sure if .listView('refresh'); is needed. Check it!
for (var i = 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
    $(".RSSclass").append('<li id="list' + i + '"><a href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '">&nbsp;</a></li>');
}


for (i = 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
    document.write('<div data-role="page" id="article' + i + '">' + '  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">' + '    <a href="#list" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-back="true">Home</a>' + '    <h1 id="articleHeader' + i + '">&nbsp;</h1>' + '    <a href="#" id="openButton' + i + '" data-role="button" data-icon="plus"' + '      class="ui-btn-right" rel="external">Open</a>' + '  </div>' + '  <div data-role="content">' + '    <div id="articleContent' + i + '" class="articleContent"></div>' + '    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">' + '      <a href="#article' + String(i - 1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l"' + '        data-inline="true" class="prevButton">Prev</a>' + '      <a href="#article' + String(i + 1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r"' + '        data-inline="true" class="nextButton" data-iconpos="right">Next</a>' + '    </div>' + '  </div>' + '</div>');
} /* JSONP */
$(function() {
    // getOnlineFeed('http://www4.lehigh.edu/news/rss/LUnews_rss.xml');
    getOnlineFeed('http://www4.lehigh.edu/news/rss/LUnews_rss.xml');

/*
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml');
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.fremont.k12.ca.us/site/RSS.aspx?DomainID=1&ModuleInstanceID=4613&PageID=1');
  getOnlineFeed('http://news.google.com/news?hl=ja&ned=us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&output=atom&topic=h');
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.appbank.net/feed');
  getOnlineFeed('http://japanese.engadget.com/rss.xml');
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.bebit.co.jp/index.xml');  
  getOnlineFeed('http://www.ntt.com/rss/release.rdf?link_id=ostop_service_rss');
  getOnlineFeed('http://feeds.feedburner.com/gapsis');
  getOnlineFeed('http://octoba.net/feed');
  getOfflineFeed('google_news_jsonp.js');
*/
}); /* functions */
var listEntries = function(json) {
    if (!json.responseData.feed.entries) return false;
    $('#widgetTitle').text(json.responseData.feed.title);
    var articleLength = json.responseData.feed.entries.length;
    articleLength = (articleLength > maxLength) ? maxLength : articleLength;
    for (var i = 1; i <= articleLength; i++) {
        var entry = json.responseData.feed.entries[i - 1];
        $('#link' + i).text(entry.title);
        $('#articleHeader' + i).text(entry.title);
        $('#openButton' + i).attr('href', entry.link);
        $('#articleContent' + i).append(entry.content);
    }
    $('#article1 .prevButton').remove();
    $('#article' + articleLength + ' .nextButton').remove();
    if (articleLength < maxLength) {
        for (i = articleLength + 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
            $('#list' + i).remove();
            $('#article' + i).remove();
        }
    }
};
var getOnlineFeed = function(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?callback=listEntries&hl=ja&output=json-in-script&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&v=1.0&num=' + maxLength);
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
};
var getOfflineFeed = function(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', url);
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
};
//]]>  

});
```

and added the CSS in the head of my html document but looks terrible...

Also i have an error : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in line :

```
$(function() {
    // getOnlineFeed('http://www4.lehigh.edu/news/rss/LUnews_rss.xml');
    getOnlineFeed('http://www4.lehigh.edu/news/rss/LUnews_rss.xml');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably set a more specific title than 'Having some trouble with jQuery mobile code'.

Comment: You will have to add the markup to the `.RSSclass` and then when done markup the whole listview by instantiating the listview such as `$('.RSSclass').listView()`

Comment: Move functions to _head_ or at the beginning of `pageshow` event.

Comment: I moved it , but i still get the same error. @Rob i dont understand what you u mean :

Comment: @JohnyJaz If you can successfully iterate over each RSS item, add that to the list `.RSSclass` then when the RSS items are all added, you must reload the listview by calling `$('.RSSclass').listView()` and jQueryMobile will add the appropriate markup to make it look like it should.  Perhaps you can get a JSfiddle working showing where it's breaking and we can take a look.

Comment: Hello @Rob , thank you very much for stopping by! Where should i add this call ? I am not sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have/had to amend the `listEntries` function as that was the one that the JSOP was calling on callback.

```
var listEntries = function (json) {
    if (!json.responseData.feed.entries) return false;
    $('#widgetTitle').text(json.responseData.feed.title);
    var articleLength = json.responseData.feed.entries.length;
    articleLength = (articleLength > maxLength) ? maxLength : articleLength;
    for (var i = 1; i <= articleLength; i++) {
        var entry = json.responseData.feed.entries[i - 1];
        $(".RSSclass").append('<li id="list' + i + '"><a href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '">' + entry.title + '</a></li>');
    }
    $('.RSSclass').listview('refresh');
};
```

Also you had to add your custom page setup into the body of the page like so:

```
<div data-role="page" id="news" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Espacio Joven</li>
            <li><a href="#news" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">News</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#agenda" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Agenda</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#info" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Info</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#activities" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Activities</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#alDia" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Al Dia</a>
            </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">La Noche Es Joven</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->
    <div data-role="header"> <a href="#mypanel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext"></a>

         <h1>News</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="RSSclass"></ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
</div>
```

Then you had to delete the content that the above script generated automatically with `document.write`

Here's a JsBin of it working. http://jsbin.com/APojAlu/1/edit?html,output
Hope that helps.

Comment: GREAT job @Rob wow! Thank you so much! However , the script now doesnt navigate me to the articles as it should :( . Supposedly when you choose one of the articles you should navigate to the article page and read the RSS feed from that article. You only show the titles in the listview. However when i click on something on the listview nothing happens. I am trying to see now , what is wrong here , but if you have some time i would appreciate your help! Thanks again man!!

Comment: @JohnyJaz Of course not as I haven't added the links in.  Are you actually able to understand the JSON output? 
Here it is with links working http://jsbin.com/APojAlu/2/

Comment: Well it seems that i dont fully undestand it, i am trying my best though. What do you mean you hadnt added the links? Also the last link you posted is not working for me so i cant see the difference in the code.

Comment: aah OK !!! Now i get it ! i added in the end of your url "/edit?html,output" and i can see it. Yes its working great now. However it kinda redirects to the web-page. The original RSS though , shows the feed in jquery mobile enviroment and then gives user the option to navigate to the page if he likes. Any idea how we could adopt this functionality too?

Comment: Try this link http://jsbin.com/APojAlu/2/edit?html,output
In the code `$(".RSSclass").append('<li id="list' + i + '"><a href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '">' + entry.title + '</a></li>');` I hadn't actually made the link anything.  I was using the code you posted above.  However by changing it to `$(".RSSclass").append('<li id="list' + i + '"><a href="' + entry.link + '" id="link' + i + '">' + entry.title + '</a></li>');` It'll work.  What purpose is this for if you're not able to understand these things?  Are we wasting our time or doing your work for you?

Comment: @JohnyJaz this is not helping anyone else anymore to discuss this here.  You can email me info@ my username .com and we can discuss further.

Comment: You are not doing my work and sorry if you feel like that. I said from the beginning that i didnt write this piece of code , i just needed help to integrate it , in a webpage. It was a bit difficult for me to see the changes you did with the code , but now i see it. Thank you for your time and help and sorry if you still feel like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35849/discussion-between-rob-schmuecker-and-johny-jaz)

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and had two error messages

- listEntries undefined
- maxLength undefined

If you put the following code before the statement `$(document).on("pageshow", '#news', function() {` they are both known and the content from your feed is displayed:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

var maxLength = 20; /* writing HTML */

function listEntries (json) {
    if (!json.responseData.feed.entries) return false;
    $('#widgetTitle').text(json.responseData.feed.title);
    var articleLength = json.responseData.feed.entries.length;
    articleLength = (articleLength > maxLength) ? maxLength : articleLength;
    for (var i = 1; i <= articleLength; i++) {
        var entry = json.responseData.feed.entries[i - 1];
        $('#link' + i).text(entry.title);
        $('#articleHeader' + i).text(entry.title);
        $('#openButton' + i).attr('href', entry.link);
        $('#articleContent' + i).append(entry.content);
    }
    $('#article1 .prevButton').remove();
    $('#article' + articleLength + ' .nextButton').remove();
    if (articleLength < maxLength) {
        for (i = articleLength + 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
            $('#list' + i).remove();
            $('#article' + i).remove();
        }
    }
};

$(document).on("pageshow", '#news', function() {
// rest follows here
```

This should get you going.

Comment: Thank you sir. However i get the exact same error as before :/ It doesnt seem to behave any differently.

Comment: Did you only added the above code or did you remove the matching parts (the var `maxLength` and `var listEntries = function()...` as well? What is your exact error message in the chrome dev tools? It would help if you post a full example of your code at jsfiddle

Comment: I added the code you said and removed the aforementioned parts.. I get the same error that : "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" as i mentioned before. You can look my edited question and see a screenshot of what exactly i get! I ll try do a fiddler as you suggest , though i have no clue how to add all my javascripts and css files in there. I could never make it work... :

Comment: Please look my edited question! I added a fidler link and i explain what exactly is happening. This is exactly the result i am getting here.

Comment: I assume that you have solved the issue. As others have already mentioned it is always good to be precise in the title: as far as i can tell you had two problems: javascript does not load feed by using googles feed api and css layout with jquery.mobile not working.